# how to add params in Http request to invoke a method on a controller in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Listing model in my rails app. I have atable with all the listings and a listing_controller class. What I want to do is invoke a method I wrote in the listing_controller. Here is this method:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  def around
      lat = params[:latitude]
      long = params[:longitude]
      @surroundings = Listing.where("latitude = :lat and longitude = :long", :lat lat, :long long)  
  end
end
```

Here is my `around.html.erb` file

```
<h1>Surroundings</h1>


<%=@surroundings.inspect%>


<br/>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
<br/>
```

Now my  listings table has 2 columns: latitude and longitude both string types.

I would like to test the "around" method that I wrote

Here is my `routes.rb` file

```
Businesses::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :listings
  root to: 'listings#index', as: 'listings'

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Now my understanding is this in order to invoke a method of a controller I need to construct a url and append the method to be invoked after listings like so....

```
http://localhost:3000/listings/around
```

but Im failing to understand how will I give the 2 parameters (latitude and longitude) to this method?? Where and how in the url can I add them..

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are talking about regular http get parameters. You can just add them to your URL beginning in the style of `?param1=value1&param2=value2&...`.

In your example, you would write something like `http://localhost:3000/listings/around?latitude=3.455&longitude=15.2228`.

To generate such a URL using the Rails helper, the syntax should be something like `listings_around_path(:latitude => "3.455", :longitude => "15.2228")`.

Comment: Thanks. However, the link_to helper that you suggested did not work. So I tried this one, it worked <td><%= link_to 'Around', {:action => 'around' } %></td>......... But, now Im trying to figure out, how can I pass the latitude and longitude as parameters

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Ruby on Rails Guides: Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) and read the section on parameters.  You can provide these parameters through the query string parameters of the URL.  For example `http://localhost:3000/listings/around?latitude=1&longitude=2`.  You can also POST this data.